# LAGG (Link aggregation) на Intel 82576

Tags: linux, сеть

В datasheet'ах Intel указано что сетевой адаптер E1G42ET поддерживает IEEE 802.3ad (link aggregation control protocol). Но при настройке LAGG в Linux используют драйвер bonding. Поэтому не понятно в чем смысл упоминать что сетевая карта поддерживает эту фичу если в линукс это реализуют по другому или можно как то настроить аппаратно сетевые адаптеры на работу по протоколу lacp? Кто нибудь может помочь внести ясность в этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel заявляет о поддержке LACP т.к. их родной драйвер для windows в настройках содержит галочку для включения транка. Думаю LACP пакеты для конфигруации линка при этом шлет сам драйвер.

В linux bounding умеет работать с протоколом LACP, для этого при загрузке драйвера надо указать режим работы `mode=4`

Linux драйвер e1000, обеспечивающий поддержку адаптеров intel, отдельной поддержки lacp не имеет. И не думаю, что кто нибудь этим займется, ибо протокол очень простой, системных ресурсов не отнимает, как таковая аппаратная поддержка для ускорения работы не требуется